# Issues with AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've written the below jQuery. The first AJAX call returns state list but the second AJAX call will not write any result of city.

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cnt_id").change(function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      var dataString = 'id=' + id;

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "a1.php",
        data: dataString,

        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          $("#state").html(html);
        }
      });
    });

    $("#state2").on('change', function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      //document.innerHTML(id+"country_id");
      var cnt_id = $("#country_id").val();
      var dataString = 'state_id=' + id + 'country_id=' + cnt_id;

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "a1.php",
        data: dataString,
        //async:true;
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          $("#city").html(html);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Debug your request, open your browser console and catch the errors you get after this request.

Comment: What does second ajax request return?

Comment: Can you provide the back-end code (i.e. the PHP logic) responsible for returning the state and the city?

Comment: There is `&` missing before `country_id=`

Comment: second ajax request return city list.

Comment: for state$SQL_STATEMENT_state =  $DatabaseCo->dbLink->query("SELECT * FROM state_view WHERE cnt_id='$country_id'and status='APPROVED'  ORDER BY state_name ASC");

 

 while($DatabaseCo->dbRow = mysqli_fetch_object($SQL_STATEMENT_state))

 {

   ?>

   <option value="<?php echo $DatabaseCo->dbRow->state_id; ?>"><?php echo $DatabaseCo->dbRow->state_name ?></option>

     <?php } ?>

Comment: for city:     SQL_STATEMENT_city =  $DatabaseCo->dbLink->query("SELECT * FROM city_view WHERE cnt_id='".$_REQUEST['country_id']."' AND state_id='".$_REQUEST['state']."' and status='APPROVED' ORDER BY city_name ASC");

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can try:

```
data: {state_id: id, country_id: cnt_id},
```

If that doesn't work I would alert those variables to make sure they have values.

Comment: sir i am used above dataString variable  that store the state id and cnt_id.

Comment: as Maxim says above, '&' separator is missing